# Excel VBA - Deleting Columns based on specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete columns in a different sheet based on certain text. So there is a sheet called the "Magical Sheet". Then there is a second sheet called "Factory 1".

Magical sheet will have document names in column A:

- Document 1
- Document 2
- Document 3

I would like the code to find columns with that text in the Factory 1 sheet and delete those columns. I think I'm using the delete function incorrectly?

At the moment I cant get it to delete any columns.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
Sub DeleteColumnsBasedOnDocumentIDs()
    Dim magicalSheet As Worksheet
    Dim factory1Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastMagicalRow As Long
    Dim magicalRange As Range
    Dim colHeader As Variant
    Dim col As Long
    
    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set magicalSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Magical Sheet")
    Set factory1Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Factory 1")
    
    ' Find the last row in the Magical Sheet
    lastMagicalRow = magicalSheet.Cells(magicalSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Define the range in the Magical Sheet
    Set magicalRange = magicalSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastMagicalRow)
    
    ' Loop through each column in Factory 1
    For col = factory1Sheet.Cells(1, factory1Sheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1
        colHeader = factory1Sheet.Cells(1, col).Value
        
        ' Check if the column header matches any document ID
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(magicalRange, colHeader) > 0 Then
            ' Delete the column
            factory1Sheet.Columns(col).Delete
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you ever getting into the If-clause? As in it tries to delete a column? If not, have you tried using Trim?

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Columns Based on a List

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**The Calling Procedure (Example)**

```
Sub DeleteColumnsBasedOnDocumentIDs()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    DeleteColumnsBasedOnList wb, "Magical Sheet", "Factory 1", "A2", "A1"
    ' continue, e.g.:
    'DeleteColumnsBasedOnList wb, "Magical Sheet", "Factory 2", "B2", "A1"
    'DeleteColumnsBasedOnList wb, "Magical Sheet", "Factory 3", "C2", "A1"
End Sub
```

**The Main Procedure**

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a given workbook ('wb'), deletes the columns of a worksheet
'               ('DeleteSheetName') whose headers are found in a list located
'               in a column of another worksheet ('DeleteSheetName').
' Remarks:      'LookupSheetFirstDataCell' is the address of the first cell
'               of a single-column range while 'DeleteSheetFirstHeaderCell'
'               is the first cell of a single-row (header) range.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub DeleteColumnsBasedOnList( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal LookupSheetName As String, _
        ByVal DeleteSheetName As String, _
        Optional ByVal LookupSheetFirstDataCell As String = "A2", _
        Optional ByVal DeleteSheetFirstHeaderCell As String = "A1")
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Columns Based on List"
    
    ' Set references to the worksheets and ranges.
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Sheets(LookupSheetName)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DeleteSheetName)
    
    Dim lrg As Range, drg As Range, cell As Range, Last As Long
    
    ' Lookup
    With lws.Range(LookupSheetFirstDataCell)
        Last = lws.Cells(lws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        If Last < .Row Then
            MsgBox "No data found in the single-column range """ _
                & .Resize(lws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, 1).Address(0, 0) _
                & """ of the Lookup sheet.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set lrg = .Resize(Last - .Row + 1, 1)
    End With
    
    ' Delete
    With dws.Range(DeleteSheetFirstHeaderCell)
        Last = dws.Cells(.Row, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If Last < .Column Then
            MsgBox "No data found in the single-row range """ _
                & .Resize(1, dws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1).Address(0, 0) _
                & """ of the Delete sheet.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set drg = .Resize(1, Last - .Column + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Combine the entire columns of the matching cells into a union
    ' and delete it.
    
    Dim dcIndexes As Variant: dcIndexes = Application.Match(drg, lrg, 0)
    
    Dim durg As Range, c As Long, IsMatch As Boolean
    
    If IsArray(dcIndexes) Then ' it's a 1D one-based array
        For c = 1 To UBound(dcIndexes)
             IsMatch = IsNumeric(dcIndexes(c))
             CombineCellColumns durg, drg.Cells(c), IsMatch
        Next c
    Else  ' it's a simple value
        IsMatch = IsNumeric(dcIndexes)
        CombineCellColumns durg, drg.Cells(1), IsMatch
    End If
    
    If durg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching headers found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    durg.Delete xlShiftToLeft
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Columns deleted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
End Sub
```

**A Helper Procedure Called by the Main Procedure**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      If 'AddFlag' is set to 'True,' it includes the entire column
'               ('.EntireColumn') of a cell ('addCell') in a range union
'               ('combinedRange').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub CombineCellColumns( _
        ByRef combinedRange As Range, _
        ByVal addCell As Range, _
        ByVal AddFlag As Boolean)
    With addCell
        If AddFlag Then
            Debug.Print "Adding cell """ & .Address(0, 0) & """(""" _
                & CStr(.Value) & """)."
            If combinedRange Is Nothing Then
                Set combinedRange = .EntireColumn
            Else
                Set combinedRange = Union(combinedRange, .EntireColumn)
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not adding cell """ & .Address(0, 0) & """(""" _
                & CStr(.Value) & """)."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Debug.Print Result (`Ctrl+G`)**

```
Not adding cell "A1"("").
Adding cell "B1"("doc3").
Not adding cell "C1"("Some1").
Not adding cell "D1"("doc4").
Adding cell "E1"("doc1").
Adding cell "F1"("doc1").
Not adding cell "G1"("other4").
Adding cell "H1"("other3").
Adding cell "I1"("doc3").
```